# Fatal PHP error bind paramater function

Tags: php, sql

I'm running this PHP script but I'm get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non object in c:/test.php on line 16

Line 16 is:

```
$load_stmt->bind_param('ss', $filetobeloaded, $filetobeloaded);
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this statement?

Full script:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'orangevalleedb');
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$file_query = "select filename from cdr";
$load_query = "LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE cdr FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ( @col_1, @col_2 )";

$file_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($file_query);
$file_stmt->execute();
$file_stmt->bind_result($filetobeloaded);

$load_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($load_query);
$load_stmt->bind_param('ss', $filetobeloaded, $filetobeloaded);

/* execute prepared statement */
while($file_stmt->fetch()) {
    $load_stmt->execute();
}

/* close statement and connection */
$load_stmt->close();
$file_stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Probably a copy&paste error. I've fixed that.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($load_stmt)` to see what you get?

Comment: As the error message says, `$load_stmt` is not an object. There's probably an error in your SQL query.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can have a bind marker in that part of the query as explained in the official [`mysqli_prepare`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) documentation:

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
> example,  they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
> (to specify column  values for a row), or in a comparison with a
> column in a WHERE clause to specify  a comparison value.`

But I may be wrong.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for confirming, wasn't 100% sure really.

Answer (score 1):

This is useful information rather than an answer.

According to the [MySQL 5.0 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) these are the only statements that can be 'prepared'.

Sadly, it doesn’t change much until version 6+ which is not commonly available.

Taken from the manual.

The following SQL statements can be used in prepared statements:

```
ALTER TABLE
CALL
COMMIT
{CREATE | DROP} INDEX
{CREATE | DROP} TABLE
DELETE
DO
INSERT
RENAME TABLE
REPLACE
SELECT
SET
SHOW (most variants)
TRUNCATE TABLE
UPDATE
```

As of MySQL 5.0.15, the following additional statements are supported:

```
{CREATE | DROP} VIEW
```

As of MySQL 5.0.23, the following additional statements are supported:

```
ANALYZE TABLE
OPTIMIZE TABLE
REPAIR TABLE
```

Other statements are not supported in MySQL 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this in your query:

```
$load_query = "LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE…"
```

As explained in the official MySQL [documentation on `LOAD DATA` page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html); emphasis mine:

> **The file name must be given as a literal string.** On Windows, specify
>   backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes.
>   The `character_set_filesystem` system variable controls the
>   interpretation of the file name.

So you should change that statement to read as:

```
$load_query = "LOAD DATA INFILE $filetobeloaded INTO TABLE cdr FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ( @col_1, @col_2 )";
```

Additionally, our bind statement on line 16 has two values:

```
$load_stmt->bind_param('ss', $filetobeloaded, $filetobeloaded);
```

But the query string being bound only has one `?` in place:

```
$load_query = "LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE cdr FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ( @col_1, @col_2 )";
```

Unclear why you have two values in the `bind_param` so perhaps just setting it to one param will work:

```
$load_stmt->bind_param('s', $filetobeloaded);
```

Comment: no it won't as its saying that $load_stmt is not an object.. irrespective of how many parameters there are.

Comment: Sorry here is the full statement: 
$load_query = "LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE cdr FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' SET  filename = ?";